# Passing variables from terminal to makefile

Tags: c, linux, vim, makefile

I'm new to Linux Mint and was wondering if it was possible if in my make file i could create a variable and then when i call the function(not sure what you would call it here) such as run or all with this variable. WHat i'm basically trying to do is from the terminal i want to do something like this:

```
make open(variable)
```

which would then pass that variable into the makefile where something like:

```
all:

    vim $(filename)
```

would receive it and open the file in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your vim example you would want:

```
make all filename=the-file.txt
```

Note that the `all` can be omitted assuming it is the first target in your Makefile.  Basically the syntax is `variable=value`

This is better demonstrated with the following Makefile:

```
echo:
    echo $(MY_ECHO)
```

if you do: `make MY_ECHO=hello` the variable `MY_ECHO` will be the string `hello`.

How you specify a target or targets is the same as when you do not use variables, you just need to make sure you have `variable=value` without any spaces so make knows whether it is a variable or target.  For example if you do:

```
make MY_ECHO= asdf
```

You will get the error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'asdf'.  Stop.
```

As make will think `asdf` is a target.  If you want to use a value with a space you need to surround it with quotes:

```
make MY_ECHO="hello world"
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your example makefile, you would call `make` from the command line as:

```
make filename=/tmp/my/file
```

Then `/tmp/my/file` would open in `vim`.